# Problems with creating and editing accounts in MVC project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, controller, actionresult

I need to be able to create new accounts (based on my model) and also edit existing accounts. I'm struggling to attempt this ,it seems to me that one of my ActionResult function (CadastrarContas) in my controller is not working as it should.. When I try to create a new account after completing the form nothing happens in the Database and my Main view returns no result. As for editing an existing account I get no changes and some of my existing accounts go missing in the main view.Can anyone give me some insight? I'll provide my code and try to be as clear as I can, if more code is needed I'll edit the post. Thanks in advance.

**Model**

```
public class Cobrancas_Contas
    {        
        [Key]
        [Display(Name = "Código")]
        public int ContaID { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = " - Campo Obrigatório")]
        [Display(Name = "Empresa")]
        public int EmpresaID { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Filial")]
        public int FilialID { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = " - Campo Obrigatório")]
        [Display(Name = "Cedente")]
        public string Nome { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = " - Campo Obrigatório")]
        [Display(Name = "Documento")]
        public string Documento { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = " - Campo Obrigatório")]
        [Display(Name = "Banco")]
        public string Banco { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = " - Campo Obrigatório")]
        [Display(Name = "Agência")]
        public string Agencia { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = " - Campo Obrigatório")]
        [Display(Name = "Agência - DV")]
        public string AgenciaDV { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = " - Campo Obrigatório")]
        [Display(Name = "Conta")]
        public string Conta { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = " - Campo Obrigatório")]
        [Display(Name = "DV - Conta")]
        public string ContaDV { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = " - Campo Obrigatório")]
        [Display(Name = "Convênio SICOV")]
        public int Convenio { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = " - Campo Obrigatório")]
        [Display(Name = "Convênio SIACC")]
        public int ConvenioSIACC { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = " - Campo Obrigatório")]
        [Display(Name = "Tipo Convênio")]
        public string TipoConvenio { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = " - Campo Obrigatório")]
        [Display(Name = "Variação")]
        public int Variacao { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = " - Campo Obrigatório")]
        [Display(Name = "Tipo")]
        public string Tipo { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = " - Campo Obrigatório")]
        [Display(Name = "Tipo de Cobrança")]
        public string Cobranca { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = " - Campo Obrigatório")]
        [Display(Name = "Especie Padrão")]
        public string EspeciePadrao { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = " - Campo Obrigatório")]
        [Display(Name = "Indicativo Padrão")]
        public string IndicativoPadrao { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = " - Campo Obrigatório")]
        [Display(Name = "Código Multa")]
        public int CodigoMulta { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = " - Campo Obrigatório")]
        [Display(Name = "Carteira")]
        public int Carteira { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = " - Campo Obrigatório")]
        [Display(Name = "Dias Multa")]
        public int DiasMulta { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = " - Campo Obrigatório")]
        [Display(Name = "Dias Baixa")]
        public int DiasBaixa { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = " - Campo Obrigatório")]
        [Display(Name = "Percentual de Juros")]
        public decimal PercentualJuros { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = " - Campo Obrigatório")]
        [Display(Name = "Percentual de Multa")]
        public decimal PercentualMultas { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Sequencial")]
        public int Sequencial { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Sequencial SICOV")]
        public int SequencialDDA { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Sequencial SIACC")]
        public int SequencialSIACC { get; set; }

        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime Cadastro { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = " - Campo Obrigatório")]
        [Display(Name = "Situação")]
        public string Situacao { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Operação")]
        public string Operacao { get; set; }

        public virtual Empresas Empresas { get; set; }
        public virtual Filiais Filiais { get; set; }
    }
```

**Main View**

```
<div class="row MAS ADM">
    <div class="col-md-12 grid">
        <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
            <tr>
                <th class="text-center">ID</th>
                <th class="text-center">Banco</th>
                <th class="text-center">Agência</th>
                <th class="text-center">Conta</th>
                <th class="text-center">Cobrança</th>
                <th class="text-center">Situação</th>
                <th class="text-center">Operação</th>
                <th class="text-center">Ação</th>
            </tr>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            CountLinhas += 1;
            int ContaID = item.ContaID;
            <tr>
                <td class="text-center">@ContaID.ToString("0000")</td>
                <td class="text-center">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Banco) </td>
                <td class="text-center">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Agencia) </td>
                <td class="text-center">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Conta) </td>
                <td class="text-center">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Cobranca)</td>
                <td class="text-center">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Situacao)</td>
                <td class="text-center">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Operacao)</td>
                <td class="text-center">
                    <a id="bt-@CountLinhas.ToString("0000")" href="/Administrativo/GetContasFiliais/?CtID=@item.ContaID" data-window="#Editar-Open" class="btn btn-default btn-xs bt-contas" title="Editar filiais desta conta"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-transfer"></span></a>
                    <a href="../Contas/Form/@item.ContaID?acao=Editar" class="btn btn-default btn-xs bt-contas" title="Editar Conta"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Form View**

```
<div id="Form" class="form-container @ViewBag.Acao">
        <div class="page-header">
            <h1>Cadastro de Contas</h1>
        </div>
        @using (Html.BeginForm(Acao, "Administrativo/Contas", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "FRMContas" }))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            <div class="panel panel-primary">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4>Preencha com as informações do formulário!</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => Model.ContaID)

                    @if (Area == "MAS" || Area == "ADM")
                    {
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmpresaID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" }) <!--Cria tag Label-->
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmpresaID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" }) <!--Cria tag span-->
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.EmpresaID, (List<SelectListItem>)lEmpresas, " - SELECIONE - ", new { @class = "form-control" }) <!--Cria tag select-->
                        </div>
                    }

                    <div class="form-group col-md-3 CampoForm">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Documento, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ContaID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ContaID, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control"} })
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group col-md-3 CampoForm">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Nome, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Nome, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Nome, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Nome" } })
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group col-md-3 CampoForm">

                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Banco, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Banco, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Banco, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", value = "", placeholder = "000", data_tipo = "numerico", maxlength = 3 } })
                        @Html.DropDownList("nomeBancos_", (List<SelectListItem>)lBancos, " - Selecione um banco -", new { @class = "form-control col-md-10" })
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group col-md-3 CampoForm">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Agencia, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Agencia, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Agencia, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "0000", data_tipo = "numerico" , maxlength = 4} })
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group col-md-3 CampoForm">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AgenciaDV, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AgenciaDV, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AgenciaDV, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "0", data_tipo = "numerico", maxlength = 1 } })
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group col-md-3 CampoForm">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Conta, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Conta, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Conta, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "00000000", data_tipo = "numerico", maxlength = 8 } })
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group col-md-3 CampoForm">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ContaDV, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ContaDV, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ContaDV, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "0", data_tipo = "numerico", maxlength = 1 } })
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group col-md-3 CampoForm">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Convenio, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Convenio, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Convenio, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Convênio", data_tipo = "numerico" } })
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group col-md-3 CampoForm">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ConvenioSIACC, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ConvenioSIACC, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ConvenioSIACC, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", data_tipo = "numerico" } })
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group col-md-3 CampoForm">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TipoConvenio, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TipoConvenio, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TipoConvenio, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", maxlength = 10} })
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group col-md-3 CampoForm">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Variacao, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Variacao, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Variacao, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", data_tipo = "numerico" } })
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group col-md-3 CampoForm">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Tipo, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Tipo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Tipo, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", maxlength = 5 } })
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group col-md-3 CampoForm">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Cobranca, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Cobranca, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Cobranca, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group col-md-3 CampoForm">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EspeciePadrao, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EspeciePadrao, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EspeciePadrao, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", maxlength = 6 } })
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group col-md-3 CampoForm">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IndicativoPadrao, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IndicativoPadrao, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.IndicativoPadrao, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", maxlength = 6 } })
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group col-md-3 CampoForm">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CodigoMulta, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CodigoMulta, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CodigoMulta, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", data_tipo = "numerico" } })
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group col-md-3 CampoForm">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Carteira, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Carteira, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Carteira, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", data_tipo = "numerico" } })
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group col-md-3 CampoForm">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DiasMulta, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DiasMulta, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DiasMulta, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", data_tipo = "numerico" } })
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group col-md-3 CampoForm">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DiasBaixa, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DiasBaixa, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DiasBaixa, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", data_tipo = "numerico" } })
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group col-md-3 CampoForm">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PercentualJuros, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PercentualJuros, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PercentualJuros, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", data_tipo = "decimal" } })
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group col-md-3 CampoForm">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Sequencial, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Sequencial, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Sequencial, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", data_tipo = "numerico" } })
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group col-md-3 CampoForm">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SequencialDDA, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SequencialDDA, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SequencialDDA, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", data_tipo = "numerico" } })
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group col-md-3 CampoForm">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SequencialSIACC, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SequencialSIACC, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SequencialSIACC, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", data_tipo = "numerico" } })
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group col-md-3 CampoForm">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Operacao, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Operacao, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Operacao, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", maxlength = 4 } })
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group col-md-3 CampoForm">
                        <label class="form-label">Cadastro</label>
                        <input id="Cadastro" name="Cadastro" type="text" readonly class="form-control" value="@Cadastro" />
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group col-md-3 CampoForm">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Situacao, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Situacao, "", new { @class = "text-danger", maxlength = 1 })
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.EmpresaID, (List<SelectListItem>)lSituacao, " - SELECIONE - ", new { @class = "form-control" })
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="panel-footer">
                    <input type="submit" value="@ViewBag.Label" class="btn btn-primary"> | @Html.ActionLink("Cancelar", "../Administrativo/Contas/", new { id = "", acao = "" }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })

                </div>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Contas(int pagina = 1, int EmID = 0, int FiID = 0, string Conta = "", string Situacao = "")
        {
            bool IsLogado = (Session["IsLogado"] is null);
            if (IsLogado)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Login", "User", new { acao = "ErroSessao" });
            };

            string Area = Session["Area"].ToString();
            int UserID = Convert.ToInt32(Session["UserID"]);
            int EmpresaID = Convert.ToInt32(Session["EmpresaID"]);
            int FilialID = Convert.ToInt32(Session["FilialID"]);

            int referenciaID = PageList.GetReferenciaID(Area, FilialID, EmpresaID, 0, 0);
            referenciaID = (Area == "MAS") ? UserID : referenciaID;

            EmID = (EmID == 0) ? EmpresaID : EmID;
            FiID = (FiID == 0) ? FilialID : FiID;

            ViewBag.EmID = EmID;
            ViewBag.FiID = FiID;
            ViewBag.Conta = Conta;
            ViewBag.Situacao = Situacao;

            //Definindo a paginação              
            int paginaQdteRegistros = (Session["RegistrosPorPagina"] == null) ? 10 : Convert.ToInt32(Session["RegistrosPorPagina"]);
            int paginaNumeroNavegacao = pagina;

            IPagedList Contas = PageList.GetAdmContas(db, paginaNumeroNavegacao, paginaQdteRegistros, Area, EmID, FiID, Conta, Situacao);
            return View(Contas);
        }
        public ActionResult FormContas(int id = 0, string acao = "")
        {

            bool IsLogado = (Session["IsLogado"] is null);
            if (IsLogado)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Login", "User", new { acao = "ErroSessao" });
            };
            ViewBag.Id = id;
            ViewBag.Acao = acao;
            ViewBag.Label = "Cadastrar";
            if (acao == "Editar") { ViewBag.Label = "Atualizar"; };
            if (id == 0)
            {
                ViewBag.EmID = 0;
                ViewBag.FiID = 0;
                return View();
            }

            Cobrancas_Contas CobContas = DBCtx.Cob_ContasDB.Find(id);
            ViewBag.EmID = CobContas.Filiais.EmpresaID;
            if (CobContas == null)
            {
                return View();
            }
            return View(CobContas);
        }

        [Route("Administrativo/Contas/Cadastrar/")]
        public ActionResult CadastrarContas(Cobrancas_Contas CobContas)
        {
            bool IsLogado = (Session["IsLogado"] is null);
            if (IsLogado)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Login", "User", new { acao = "ErroSessao" });
            };
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View("FormContas", CobContas);
            }

            int ContaID = CobContas.ContaID;

            if (ContaID == 0)
            {
                DBCtx.Cob_ContasDB.Add(CobContas);
            }
            else
            {
                DBCtx.Entry(CobContas).State = EntityState.Modified;
            }

            DBCtx.SaveChanges();

            ViewModelSucesso ViewMS = new ViewModelSucesso();
            ViewMS.Controller = "Administrativo";
            ViewMS.View = "Contas";
            return View("Sucesso", ViewMS);

        }
```

**Route Config**

```
public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "AdmContasFRM",
                url: "Administrativo/Contas/Form/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Empresas", action = "FormContas", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
            routes.MapRoute(
                 name: "AdmContasCadastrar",
                 url: "Administrativo/Contas/Cadastrar/",
                 defaults: new { controller = "Empresas", action = "CadastrarContas"}
             );
            routes.MapRoute(
               name: "AdmContas",
               url: "Administrativo/{action}/{id}",
               defaults: new { controller = "Empresas", action = "Contas", id = UrlParameter.Optional, busca = UrlParameter.Optional, vencDe = UrlParameter.Optional, vencAte = UrlParameter.Optional, pagina = UrlParameter.Optional }
           );
    }
}
```

Comment: add try catch `DBCtx.SaveChanges();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was conflicting routes, in my configuration I had this:

```
public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
             name: "AdmIndicesFRM",
             url: "Administrativo/Indices/Form/{id}",
             defaults: new { controller = "Empresas", action = "FormIndices", id = UrlParameter.Optional}
         );
        routes.MapRoute(
             name: "AdmIndicesCadastrar",
             url: "Administrativo/Indices/Cadastrar/",
             defaults: new { controller = "Empresas", action = "CadastrarIndices" }
         );
        routes.MapRoute(
             name: "AdmIndices",
             url: "Administrativo/{action}/{id}",
             defaults: new { controller = "Empresas", action = "Indices", id = UrlParameter.Optional, busca = UrlParameter.Optional, vencDe = UrlParameter.Optional, vencAte = UrlParameter.Optional, pagina = UrlParameter.Optional }
         );
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "AdmContasFRM",
            url: "Administrativo/Contas/Form/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Empresas", action = "FormContas", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
        routes.MapRoute(
             name: "AdmContasCadastrar",
             url: "Administrativo/Contas/Cadastrar/",
             defaults: new { controller = "Empresas", action = "CadastrarContas"}
         );
        routes.MapRoute(
           name: "AdmContas",
           url: "Administrativo/{action}/{id}",
           defaults: new { controller = "Empresas", action = "Contas", id = UrlParameter.Optional, busca = UrlParameter.Optional, vencDe = UrlParameter.Optional, vencAte = UrlParameter.Optional, pagina = UrlParameter.Optional }
       );
    }
}
```

I changed the declaration order into this and my problem was solved.

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
             name: "AdmIndicesFRM",
             url: "Administrativo/Indices/Form/{id}",
             defaults: new { controller = "Empresas", action = "FormIndices", id = UrlParameter.Optional}
         );
        routes.MapRoute(
             name: "AdmIndicesCadastrar",
             url: "Administrativo/Indices/Cadastrar/",
             defaults: new { controller = "Empresas", action = "CadastrarIndices" }
         );
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "AdmContasFRM",
            url: "Administrativo/Contas/Form/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Empresas", action = "FormContas", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
        routes.MapRoute(
             name: "AdmContasCadastrar",
             url: "Administrativo/Contas/Cadastrar/",
             defaults: new { controller = "Empresas", action = "CadastrarContas"}
         );
        routes.MapRoute(
           name: "AdmContas",
           url: "Administrativo/Contas/{id}",
           defaults: new { controller = "Empresas", action = "Contas", id = UrlParameter.Optional, busca = UrlParameter.Optional, vencDe = UrlParameter.Optional, vencAte = UrlParameter.Optional, pagina = UrlParameter.Optional }
       );
        routes.MapRoute(
             name: "AdmIndices",
             url: "Administrativo/{action}/{id}",
             defaults: new { controller = "Empresas", action = "Indices", id = UrlParameter.Optional, busca = UrlParameter.Optional, vencDe = UrlParameter.Optional, vencAte = UrlParameter.Optional, pagina = UrlParameter.Optional }
         );
    }
}
```